# How can I convert String to Map with a Map as one of the "values"?

Tags: java, dictionary

Could someone please help me to convert this `String` into a `Map`...

```
String str = "{"id":1,"result":[{"employeeId":131969,"id":1164299,"name":"Prosjekt","javaClass":"no.tripletex.tcp.model.Project","number":"","displayName":"Prosjekt"}]}"
```

Comment: What language are you working with? You can't expect people to guess here.

Comment: I am curious. I assume you did not generate the string. Were you not told it is in `json` format?

Comment: Just to add on, here is a tutorial on GSON for your reference. http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the format of your string, it seems like you need a JSON parser, no matter what language you are using.

There are many json parser [here](http://www.json.org/)

Here is a Java [json parser](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples), you may follow its example.